# VNC viewer error "Timed out waiting for response from the computer"

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, x11-forwarding, vnc-viewer

I have a docker container for Selenium Chrome node
It is hosted on a ubuntu docker node.Docker host is a AWS node, no access to GUI.

Exposed port 5900 of docker container to 32771 port of docker host.

Through NGINX enabled dummy DNS and mapped port of docker host node 80 to the localhost:32771

```
      listen         80;
      server_name    vnc-node1.com;
      location / {
           proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:32771;
}
```

Now accessing the dummay DNS `vnc.node1.com` using VNC Viewer on Windows machine to view the GUI of the selenium chrome container. But, getting the error **"Timed out waiting for response from the computer"**

When run the echo $DISPLAY on Docker host node, there is no output.
Also when run the `X11VNC -display:0` on docker host node, `XOpenDisplay failed (:0)` error is displayed.

Tried searching, but didnot find any concrete solution.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!